# Ignore specific error in pandas to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I understand that the Pandas to_datetime doesn't support dates greater than "2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807" and lesser than "1677-09-22 00:12:43.145225". I want to ignore that so that I'm not manipulating the data and returning it as it is from the source. If I use errors=ignore," I'm afraid it will ignore all the errors, but I want to ignore only the error-related "outofbounds" that are greater or lesser than the specified date range. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: What is it that you want to do if you encounter a date outside the possible range of dates?

Comment: Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code, if you have already made an attempt to solve this problem, necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: If the date falls outside the range I want to ignore the error and return the date as it is. But if there are any other errors that should be raised

Comment: Pandas version >= 2.0 removes the date limitations

Comment: I understand this error will be fixed in future when pandas switch to arrows. But with the current version of pandas 2.0.3 the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I would "modify" pandas function in order to make the error handling on ValueError. Take into account that the "to_datetime" function in pandas only raises two exceptions: ValueError and ParserError.

```
def custom_to_datetime(dt, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(dt, *args, **kwargs)
    except ValueError:
        return dt

df['date'] = custom_to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes, defnitely it helps.

Comment: I just realised that if there is bad data in one row, the entire dataframe will be skipped. Is there a way to skip only that row?